# GET Method to Weather API with username and password in URL does not work

Tags: php, get, ibm-cloud, weather-api

I found my username and password in IBM Cloud Docs Weather.

I have this code:

```
print file_get_contents("https://d40845df-8125-441f-8e7c-e650726ce721:password@twcservice.mybluemix.net/v1/location/30339:4:US/forecast/hourly/48hour.json");
// of course, the password is my password
```

The result on my website is Unauthorized.Array()

What's wrong?

I can go to Weather API on https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/rest-api/ and here is clickable API for weather.

It looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLWgm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoulQ.png)

When I fill empty inputs and click on **Try it out!** I get no response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUArw.png)

On IBM Cloud Docs Weather I found username and password with GET url.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlT94.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they require some authorization after all.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/33.40/-83.42/forecast/hourly/48hour.json'
```

I've ran the curl in linux terminal and got unathorized.

Same when You try to enter the url directly in browser.

Looking on this: http://www.remkohde.com/2016/11/14/add-serverless-programming-and-data-integration-on-bluemix/

I think You do need some authorization:

```
curl -X GET "https://<username>:<password>@twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/33.40/-83.42/forecast/daily/10day.json?units=m&language=en-US"
```

I think that the api might be outdated or something since even the online test returns strange response code **0**.